# Why is Predicate.isEqual implemented the way it is?

Tags: java, java-8

Lately I've been fiddling around with the new java8 features to have a better understanding of them.

When trying some stuff with `Stream.filter` I came across the source of `Predicate.java` in which I found the following implementation of the `isEqual` method:

```
/**
 * Returns a predicate that tests if two arguments are equal according
 * to {@link Objects#equals(Object, Object)}.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of arguments to the predicate
 * @param targetRef the object reference with which to compare for equality,
 *               which may be {@code null}
 * @return a predicate that tests if two arguments are equal according
 * to {@link Objects#equals(Object, Object)}
 */
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return (null == targetRef)
            ? Objects::isNull
            : object -> targetRef.equals(object);
}
```

What made me wonder was this line: `: object -> targetRef.equals(object);`.

Maybe I am massively overthinking this, but I couldn't help immediately thinking why that line wasn't `: targetRef::equals;` like this:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return (null == targetRef)
            ? Objects::isNull
            : targetRef::equals;
}
```

Seems to me a unnecessary creation of a lambda otherwise.

Unless I'm missing something, to me those do the same. (They are the same right?) Is there any reason why the current implementation was chosen? Or is this just something incredibly small that it just got overlooked or nobody really cared.

Guess that actually results in a bonus question: Is there any benefit in using one way over the other? Like some kind of (probably very small) performance bonus?

Comment: A method reference ends up in the same grinding machine as an explicit lambda. You need the same implementation techniques for both.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, but by creating a lamba (which only calls the method anyway) instead of passing the method reference arent we adding a unnecessary method-call (the lambda) to the chain? (Which presumably is going to be called a lot if the stream contains lots of items)

Comment: I think no-one is going to be able to answer this... expect the person that wrote the code... And even then, not so sure.

Comment: This is the predicate factory and will be called just once per stream construction. And in both cases there's the same instance of functional interface whose method is being called. It's all exactly the same.

Comment: @OlleKelderman there is no real difference at runtime. A method reference is cleaner IMHO, but at runtime the amount of work done and the number of objects created is the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so basically im massively overthinking this like I said in the question? :P

Comment: @OlleKelderman a little but it's good to understand the difference even though is won't matter 99% of the time. See my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why was it done this way?

Pure speculation but, perhaps when it was written the developer was more comfortable with the -> and possibly :: didn't even work at that time. The libraries were being written while they were fixing bugs in the compiler.

There is no way to know and even the person who write it probably doesn't remember.

---

Whether you use a method reference or a closure syntax, the same number of objects is created in most cases (as in this example)

> Guess that actually results in a bonus question: Is there any benefit in using one way over the other? Like some kind of (probably very small) performance bonus?

Using a method reference means one less method call. This could have an indirect impact on inlining as the number of levels is limited to 9 by default.  For example

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<String> lambda = s-> printStackTrace(s);
        lambda.accept("Defined as a lambda");

        Consumer<String> methodRef = Main::printStackTrace;
        methodRef.accept("Defined as a method reference");
    }


    static void printStackTrace(String description) {
        new Throwable(description).printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

prints

```
java.lang.Throwable: Defined as a lambda
    at Main.printStackTrace(Main.java:15)
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:6)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)

java.lang.Throwable: Defined as a method reference
    at Main.printStackTrace(Main.java:15)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

In the first case, the compiler has generated a method called `Main.lambda$main$0` which contains the code which actually calls `printStackTrace`

Where using one or the other makes more difference is when you could have a capturing (saves a value) or non-capturing lambda. A non-capturing lambda is only created once.

e.g.

```
Consumer<String> print1 = System.out::println; // creates an object each time
Consumer<String> print2 = s->System.out.println(s); // creates an object once.
```

In the first case, if you call `System.setOut` it will ignore this change as it has it's own copy of the PrintStream to write to.

Comment: oh wow, you just blew my mind with that example! Never thought of that.

Comment: As for the initial question of why it was done this way, guess the answer is "we'll most likely never know, and it probably doesn't matter"?

Comment: @OlleKelderman now imagine a Set of lambdas, in the first case if you add this twice you get a set of 2, in the second case you get a set of 1. Attempt to remove one and you might get a size of 2 and 0 respectively,.

Comment: @OlleKelderman perhaps when it was written the developer was more comfortable with the `->` and possibly `::` didn't even work at that time. The libraries were being written while they were fixing bugs in the compiler. ;)

Comment: Can you expand on "one less method call"? Which call is eliminated?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in a lambda style syntax, a `static` method is added to the class which contains the actual code and a method reference to this generated method is added to the byte code. If you use a method reference syntax, this extra static method is not added which means there is one less level to inline.

Comment: I see... although it would probably be very easy to detect a single-method-call lambda and eliminate the `static` method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in theory it could, but given the cost at runtime is very low and the javac does very few optimisations, I doubt this will ever happen. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Since the expression contains an `Objects::isNull`, it’s not very likely that the author “was more comfortable with the ->” nor that :: didn't work. It might be that the `instance::method` form was not working or unknown to the author, but there seems to be a preference for the :: operator as otherwise, it would be `object -> Objects.isNull(object)`…

Comment: @Holger good point, though the class might not have been updated by one person or all at once.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: of course, there could be multiple authors, but this would raise the question why whoever replaced the first lambda with `Objects::isNull` did not replace the second, which is basically the same question as before…

Comment: @Holger often when a class is updated/added to, the developer doesn't review the whole class to see what other changes s/he could make.

Comment: We’re talking about two sub-expressions of the same conditional expression in adjacent lines. A developer changing code *should* take the time to read the entire statement…

Comment: @Holger good point. In that case I think your suggested reason is the most likely.